# SSRS: Repeat tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I want to be able to repeat the Tablix in SSRS based on a the number of unique rows. 
that is, if i have the following data

```
Col1          Col2
-----------------------
1             abc
2             def
2             ghi
```

I want to be able to display one table(table1) as

```
Col1          Col2
------------------------
1             abc
```

and another table(table2) below table1 displaying data as

```
Col1          Col2
------------------------
2             def
2             ghi
```

The number of tables need to be dynamically decided based on number of unique entries in database. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is it an absolute requirement that they are different tables?  I ask because simply using row groups in a single table would achieve the same effect both conceptually and visually on the report.  Are you familiar with row groups?

Comment: Hi, I did use row groups but i wasnt able to repeat the header for every group. Also,If i use row groups, it will provide a continuous grouping of data. While the requirement is that each of these groups need to be displayed with some space between them.

Comment: You can insert rows between the groups and manually size them to produce the appearance of seperation.  You can also insert row headers.  I still think row groups is the way to go here.

Comment: True, but then, if i have to maintain some textboxes & Lines to divide the groups as if into sections,this wouldnt really be possible by doing groups isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a small number of distinct values for `Col1` you could use a list based on Col1, and use a **subreport inside the list** that displays the tables (pass the value for Col1 as a parameter).

This answer won't work if you have many different values for Col1, because this will bog down performance of your report.

Comment: Hi,As of now i have very limited values in DB and hence would like to see different options.. Im trying out the solution you suggested, however, am stil not able to achieve what i want.. though it looks promising with regard to the layout. Could please provide a guide on how to achieve this?

Comment: Add a list to the report, link it to your dataset, group it on Col1, then [add a subreport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348(v=sql.100).aspx) which has a parameter `@Col1`. Use that parameter in the `WHERE` clause of your subreport's dataset and populate a table with the data.

Comment: Hi, I tried as you suggested & was able to do it, however the subreport gets reported as many times as number of entries in one group. So, if first group(distinct value on col1) had 4 entries in col2, the subreport got repeated 4 times and then followed with the second group. Couldnt really understand why that was happening.

Comment: The example dataset from your question should only return 2 rows (distinct values of Col1) in the dataset. If for some reason you're not able to do that `GROUP BY Col1` aggregate in the dataset, then you could try grouping the data inside the list (in SSRS) on Col1.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, Still working on that problem. but it seems we have a large database with hundreds of entries. So as you said, this solution does seem impractical. Any other ways you think we could do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, the only other option I can think of was already given by @RThomas in comments to the question: use row groups.

Comment: hmm.. ok thanks for that! Will see how we proceed ahead with this problem now!

Comment: Good luck! Don't forget to get back and post (possibly as an answer to your own question) how you finally solved it, so future visitors for this question can see.